# Line integral in intersection plane and sphere

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am trying to find the integral $\int_{C} x^2 dl $, where C is the intersection betweeen the $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ sphere and the $x+y+z=0$ plane. I know how to parametrize the sphere but I don't know how to move through the points for which the plane sphere also holds. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to find an arclength parameterization of this intersection. 
Here is one such parameterization:

$$\cos \left(t\right)\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},0\right)+\sin \left(t\right)\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}},-\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}},-\frac{2}{\sqrt{6}}\right)$$

The $x$-component of this parameterization is the following: 
$$-\frac{\cos (t)}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{\sin (t)}{\sqrt{6}}$$

Through a lot of calculation, you can show the following:
$$\left(\frac{\cos (t)}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{\sin (t)}{\sqrt{6}}\right)^2=\frac{1}{3}\sin \left(2x+\frac{\pi }{6}\right)+\frac{1}{3}$$

So, we are trying to compute the following integral:
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\left[\frac{1}{3}\sin \left(2x+\frac{\pi }{6}\right)+\frac{1}{3}\right]dt$$

Before even starting, we notice that the midline of this sine wave is $\displaystyle\frac{1}{3}$ and the the period is $\pi$, which divides $2\pi$ evenly.

So, we already know that the integral has to be equal to $\displaystyle\frac{2\pi}{3}$.

Comment: Thanks! Any standard method to find such parametrizations?

Comment: For this problem, I knew the intersection was a circle with radius 1 with its center at the origin. So, I knew I could find an arclength parameterization if I found 2 radii and used sine and cosine. I think if you have a parameterization of a path, say $\big(X(t),Y(t),Z(t)\big)$, you could probably use the following parameterization:
$$\big(X(\phi^{-1}(t)),Y(\phi^{-1}(t)),Z(\phi^{-1}(t))\big) \text{ where } \phi(t)=\int_0^t\sqrt{\left[X'(k)\right]^2+\left[Y'(k)\right]^2+\left[Z'(k)\right]^2}dk$$